# Session flash message executing two times Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am having problems with my session flash message

I have a simple logic like this

```
if(empty($code))
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('modal', 'working');
        }
```

And in my view file I am doing alert for testing

```
@if(session('modal'))
  <script>
    alert('working');
  </script>
@endif
```

The problem is this `alert('working');` gets executed two times. So, when it's redirecting back, one time it immediately executes and second time, it executes after loading document.

I tried various workarounds like deleting session key, loading on document ready for javascript, but nothing works.

What could be the issue?

Comment: You're probably have it twice in your html code. Can  you inspect html code with browser and check whether your have it twice?

Comment: Can you paste the controller and the blade you're having issues with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using bootstrap...

Here is how I'd approach it:

Within your views make a new folder named: alerts and within that make a file named alerts.blade.php

Paste:

```
@if (Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{ Session::get('success') }}
    </div>
@elseif (Session::has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{ Session::get('error') }}
    </div>
@elseif(Session::has('warning'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{ Session::get('warning') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Within each file you have, you can now use: `include('alerts.alerts')`

Now within your controller, if you wish to flag an error/warning or success message simply use:

```
Session::flash('success', 'Success message here')

return redirect()->back();


Session::flash('error', 'Error message here')

return redirect()->back();


Session::flash('warning', 'warning message here')

return redirect()->back();
```

This way you don't have to keep adding HTML to every page that will hold any kind of message as you can simply just include one file which will flag up when called.

The initial make up seems a bit long winded I know but ultimately it'll save you a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

You should user laravel [flash](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#flash-data) helper like this,

`$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');`

`return back();`